# page loading from footer using rails 4 with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Here I have simple app in Rails using html. My app loads from bottom on all the pages and not from top. I used a fix for a while which covered up this issue like this:

```
<body onLoad="window.parent.scroll(0,0);">
```

But now I have to add animation while scrolling from top to bottom. Now a proper solution has to be there so that my page loads normally and **able to scroll down** and the animation works.

Here is the application.html.erb

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= render "layouts/header" %>
<%= yield %>
<%= render "layouts/footer" %>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using font-awesome and bootstrap.

Comment: Your page shouldn't be loading from the bottom. Do you have anything out of the ordinary which may cause it to do so?